# Relating the sheaf associated to a cyclic module over an affine scheme to the structure sheaf

Tags: commutative-algebra, schemes, affine-schemes, coherent-sheaves, quasicoherent-sheaves

Let $(X,\mathcal O_X)$ be the affine scheme of a commutative Noetherian ring $R$. Let $J$ be an ideal of $R$. From the sheaf $\mathcal O_X$ and the closed subset $Z:=V(J)$ of $X$ , how do we recover the sheaf of $\mathcal O_X$-modules on $X$ associated to the $R$-module $R/J$ ? Is it  $\mathcal O_X|_Z:=i^{-1}(\mathcal O_X)$ or $i^*(\mathcal O_X)$ (where $i:Z \to X$ is the inclusion) or something else ?

(In case it is unclear, by the sheaf associated to an $R$-module $M$, I mean the sheaf which takes every basic open set of the form $D(f)$ of $X$ to the localization $M_f$ )

NOTE: I guess strictly speaking, neither $\mathcal O_X|_Z$ nor $i^*(\mathcal O_X)$ is a Sheaf on $X$ but rather on $Z$. By the comment of user Ruben du Burck below it seems like the sheaf on $X$ I'm looking for is $i^*(\mathcal O_X)$ extended to $X$ by zero outside of $Z$ i.e. just $i_*(i^*(\mathcal O_X))$. But I'm still on the lookout for a definite answer. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not an expert, so correct me if I'm wrong. I believer $Z = \text{Spec}(R/J)$, so its structure sheaf $\mathcal O_Z$ is what you want. Then if $\iota : Z \to X$ is the inclusion then $\iota^*\mathcal O_X \simeq \mathcal O_Z$. The symbolic expression $\mathcal O_X |_Z$ has multiple definitions based on the author. I've seen it defined as $\iota^*\mathcal O_X$ or $\iota^{-1}\mathcal O_X$.

Comment: @Ruben du Burck: yes, $Z$ is indeed isomorphic to $Spec(R/J)$ as Schemes ... I guess my only confusion is that $\mathcal O_Z$ is a sheaf of rings on $Z$ , although basically it can also be thought of as $\mathcal O_X$-modules if I actually look at what are the rings to each basic open set ... I guess I would have to extend it to whole of $X$ ... in any case , let's see if anyone else has any take on it

Comment: $\mathcal O_Z$ is a sheaf of $\mathcal O_Z$ modules as you say, but $\iota^* \mathcal O_Z$ is a sheaf of $\mathcal O_X$ modules. This is analogous to how $R/J$ can br seen as an $R/J$ and as an $R$- module.

Comment: @Ruben du Burck: I assume you mean $i_*(\mathcal O_Z)$ ... ? Yeah I figured that too ... see my edit

Comment: sorry, that's what I meant indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot recover $R/J$ from just the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$ and the set $Z$; if you could, that would mean any two ideals $J,J'$ with $V(J)=V(J')$ are the same, but this is not true.

If you know $Z$ not just as a closed subset of $X$ but as the closed *subscheme* assoociated to the ideal $J$, then the sheaf on $X$ you seek is just $i_*(\mathcal{O}_Z)\cong i_*(i^*(\mathcal{O}_X))$.  This follows immediately from the fact that if $\varphi:A\to B$ is a homomorphism of rings with corresponding morphism of schemes $f:\operatorname{Spec} B\to \operatorname{Spec} A$, then the operation $f_*$ on quasicoherent sheaves corresponds to taking a $B$-module and considering it as an $A$-module via $\varphi$, and the operation $f^*$ corresponds to $B\otimes_A -$.  In this case, $A=R$ and $B=R/J$, so to get $R/J$ as an $R$-module, you just take $i_*(\mathcal{O}_Z)$, and $\mathcal{O}_Z$ is also the same as $i^*(\mathcal{O}_X)$ since $R/J\otimes_R R\cong R/J$.